# looping an if statement in a setstate

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a random dice generator with 2 dice. I'm using a compare statement to check the random result of the two dice and re roll if they are the same. here is the code to roll one of the dice

```
void Roll1() {
    setState(() {
      oneDiceNumber = Random().nextInt(6) + 1;
  if (oneDiceNumber == twoDiceNumber) {
        oneDiceNumber = Random().nextInt(6) + 1;
        twoDiceNumber = Random().nextInt(6) + 1;
      }
    });
  }
```

what I want the code to do is loop the if statement until it gets a result that isn't a tie.

thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a while loop

```
oneDiceNumber = 0;
twoDiceNumber = 0;

while(oneDiceNumber == twoDiceNumber){
   oneDiceNumber = Random().nextInt(6) + 1;
    twoDiceNumber = Random().nextInt(6) + 1;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could also do this using `recursion`:
Define a function called getRandomDice():

```
getRandomDice() {
   int oneDiceNumber = Random().nextInt(6) + 1;
   int twoDiceNumber = Random().nextInt(6) + 1;
   if (oneDiceNumber == twoDiceNumber) {
       return getRandomDice();
   } else {
       return [oneDiceNumber, twoDiceNumber];
   }
}
```

and you could call this using in your function like this:

```
List<int> values = getRandomDice();
int firstNum = values[0];
int secondNum = values[1];
```

Comment: It's pretty bad advice to introduce recursion when a simple loop will do.  I guess you've never had a stackoverflow.  And I don't mean the name of the site. :)

Comment: Actually I had a stack overflow error. I was just trying to show a different method of doing the same thing. It's up to the OP to use it or not.

Comment: But the chance of having it in current condition is extremely low if not impossible.